# Creating a book based on an article (copyright issues)

Tags: publications, books, publishers

I've [asked this question at math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195824/creating-a-book-based-on-an-article-copyright-issues), but a comment proposed me to ask this question at  academia.stackexchange.com instead.

Here is my question:

Elsevier [explicitly permits](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/authorsview.authors/rights) me to make a book based on my article published with Elsevier.

What's about other publishers? May these forbid me to make a book based on my earlier article?

Comment: Are you trying to make a list of publishers that allow publishing  earlier articles. If you have some specific publisher(s) in mind, that would be a better question here.

Comment: Check with each publisher that publishes one of your articles.

Comment: I suppose all research books are written based on some old and recent articles whether the previous articles are written by the author or other researchers. So I do not see what the problem is.

Comment: @Vahid: Almost all books draw ideas from articles, but I think this question is talking about reusing text from the articles.

Comment: @Anonymous Mathematician: I have seen this issue in a book written by Alain Connes and Matilda Marcolli, see Chapter 3 of the book "Noncommutative Geometry, Quantum Fields
and Motives". So I think it is not unethical, especially if we quote them.

Comment: @Vahid: Certainly a citation is always required, but it also legally requires permission of the copyright owner.  For the papers used in Chapter 3 of that book, copyright is (probably) held by Elsevier and Springer, so if Connes and Marcolli reused nontrivial amounts of text, then permission was required.  In mathematics it is generally not hard to get permission, so it's not a big deal, but it's important to deal with the legal technicalities when publishing a book (the publisher will insist on it, because they do not want to be sued).

Comment: @Anonymous Mathematician: About the legal technicalities you are right. But from the ethical standpoint I think it is okay. Although it is generally expected that a book contain more details than the content of the original papers. And this makes the author(s) to rewrite the text in order to provide a wider view of the subject. Again, I agree we should consider the legal issues as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is stated in each copyright transfer agreement (CTA) signed for publishing each paper. If the form says it is okay, then it is. Usually you can get your hand on the typical CTA used by a publisher on its website.

I would advise never to sign a CTA that does not allow reuse of the article content for a book, a dissertation and collected works.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to publish the book and you have found one publisher that allows it.

Why do you seek more?

Elaborate what is wrong about Elsevier that makes you not to pursue it with them?

Comment: There are a few reasons why I seek more: 1. Elsevier may reject to publish some of my articles (many math articles and even articles by future Nobel laureates are published after several rejections, it is not counted wrong). 2. I may want to publish with open access what at Elsevier is possible only if I pay the cost from my own pocket. 3. There is a boycott of Elsevier and I'd prefer to be a strikebreaker as little as possible, only in the case if I really need Elsevier.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check the particular policies of each publisher to see what is allowed and what is not allowed. However, it is important to remember that the journal's copyright protections are limited to how the material is *expressed* in the paper, and not the underlying ideas themselves.

Typically, that means that you won't be able to "recycle" text and figures from the article into a book. However, an expansion and reworking of the ideas normally is *not* subject to copyright violation claims, particularly if you're the author of the paper which was expanded in the first place. (This normally gives you additional privileges, depending on the publishers in question.)