# How to convert a PhD Thesis written on published articles into a book?

Tags: research-process, thesis, books, publishers

Is it a good idea to convert Thesis (computer science field) written on the basis of my own published research articles into a book?

Taking care of text recycling and copyright plus wider knowledge achieved in the subject, is it worth to go for publishing book?

If yes, how it could be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a book based on an article (copyright issues)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/creating-a-book-based-on-an-article-copyright-issues)

Comment: @Anton Menshov. It's partial answer. I will avoid text recycling and add new material to bypass copyright. My concern is, using the same information (avoiding similarity) plus wider knowledge achieved in the subject, is it worth to go for publishing book?

Comment: And then the question would be too dependent on individual factors AND/OR opinion-based.

Comment: You need to indicate your scientific field. In many fields, the answer is simply that there is no value for young scientists in writing a book.

Comment: Thank you both for raising the queries.

Comment: It happens regularly (at least in Europe) that newly graduated PhDs are contacted by "predatory" publishers. They say something along the lines of "We read your work and it is super interesting and should be published as a book". If  you got an email or phonecall similar to this you should probably ignore them. They are only interested in your money. Otherwise the answer is opinion based and depends on individual factors, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: @Louic. Thanks for noticing the Trend. I am planning to publish it with top and recognised publishers as like Springer, CRC Press, Wiley, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't speak to the question of "how?" but will address "why?".

Writing a book is a long hard job, even when you are "only" concatenating published papers. Finding a publisher is as hard. So you should think about writing a book (now, or at any stage of your career) when you think you have something book-length to say that people will really want to read in that form.

That suggests (to me) probably not for you now.